# Could someone explain how the sequence of code for a 4-bit CLA adder works?

Tags: verilog

Here is the code I wrote for my lab assignment that consisted of creating a 4-bit CLA adder using modules:

```
module lab (A,B,Ci,S,Co,PG,GG);
input [3:0]A,B;
input Ci;
output [3:0]S;
output Co,PG,GG;
wire [3:0] C, P, G;

fulladder fa0(A[0],B[0],C[0],G[0],P[0],S[0]);
fulladder fa1(A[1],B[1],C[1],G[1],P[1],S[1]);
fulladder fa2(A[2],B[2],C[2],G[2],P[2],S[2]);
fulladder fa3(A[3],B[3],C[3],G[3],P[3],S[3]);

CLALogic logic(G,P,Ci,C,Co,PG,GG);

endmodule 


module CLALogic(G,P,Ci,C,Co,PG,GG);
input [3:0]P,G;
input Ci;
output [3:0]C;
output Co,PG,GG;

assign C[0] = Ci;
assign C[1] = G[0] | (P[0] & C[0]);
assign C[2] = G[1] | (P[1] & C[1]);
assign C[3] = G[2] | (P[2] & C[2]);
assign Co = G[3] | (P[3] & C[3]);

assign PG = P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & P[0];
assign GG = G[3] | (P[3] & (G[2] & (P[2] & (G[1] | (P[1] & G[0])))));

endmodule


module fulladder (Ai,Bi,Cin,G,P,Sum);
input Ai,Bi,Cin;
output G,P,Sum;

assign G = Ai & Bi;
assign P = Ai ^ Bi;
assign Sum = P ^ Cin;


endmodule
```

It functions correctly and outputs correct values when given inputs, but I am a little lost on how exactly the value is calculated. I understand the logic behind a CLA adder, where the carry is calculated separately from the sum, I am a bit confused on how the code itself works properly.

The main part I am wondering about is how the sum calculation accounts for the initial carry-in, or carries in general, since the sum bits are calculated using wire C before the logic module that calculates the values for C is called. Wouldn't this lead to sum being calculated and ignoring any carries that may happen from previous digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules represent hardware hierarchy, they do not get *called* like a procedure in a software programming language. In your design, the contents of all module instantiations get flatten into one giant set of concurrent continuous assignments.

Any signal change on the RHS of a  continuous assignment causes an expression evaluation, and if that results in the LHS changing, that change propagates to whatever assignments it feeds into. That ripples throughout all the assignments until there is nothing left to change.

That is the nature of combinational hardware logic.